Is there a way of adjusting the width of the dropdown menu from a combobox?
Image
I'm able to adjust the width of my ctkCombobox no problem, but when i click the arrow for the dropdown list, the dropdown menu is a fixed size. It looks ridiculous when my combobox is set to 500px. Do any of you know if it's possible to adjust the width of the dropdown menu?
I've tried to google for a solution, but can't find anyone having similar issues. I've also tried some of the methods, but none of them resize my dropdown menu.
